# Copying the content of a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, copy, double

I want to copy a 2D array into another one without using the following (as an example):

```
    double Array1[10][10];
    double Array2[10][10];

    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
            for(int l=0; l<10; l++){
            Array1[k][l] = k;
            }
    }



    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
            for(int l=0; l<10; l++){
            Array2[k][l] = Array1[k][l];
            }
    }
```

So do you have any idea, how to do that in a more elegant way, maybe with one or no for loop?

Because I also need to do that for a 4D array, and that could last quite long, if these have a large number of elements.

Best regards

Comment: Use `memcpy(Array2, Array1, sizeof(Array1));`

Comment: My `memcpy` is valid because of the way you allocate the arrays. For other ways of allocating the arrays it might not be valid.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh okay, yeah in real i allocate the arrays using malloc and calloc like:

double** Array1 = safe_malloc(dim*sizeof(*Array1));

for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
       Array1[i] = safe_calloc(dim, sizeof(**Array1)); }

Comment: You can use `memcpy` for a row-based copy (i.e. of the `calloc(dim*sizeof(double))`)